# How to add a region at run time in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Without defining my region in my theme info file, how can I create a region programmatically, so that if the region has some content then it will displayed automatically in my `.tpl` file where I have printed the region variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you need to do it programmatically? Regions are just content holders for content (usually blocks). I recommend you to read about blocks first: https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/block

Comment: In one of my project I need to add a region in one of my callback defined in my hoo_meny. For all other callbacks I dont need the region.

Comment: Ok, i can't understand where you would need this.. but here is answer: http://www.webomelette.com/how-programatically-add-region-your-theme-drupal

Comment: Thankyou so much for the link, really appreciate you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [hook_system_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_system_info_alter/7) to alter information parsed from  any modules and themes `.info` files.

Code sample:

```
function [YOUR_MODULE]_system_info_alter(&$info, $file, $type)
{
    if ($type == "theme" && $file == "YOUR_THEME_MACHINE_NAME")
    {
        $info['regions']['my_new_region'] = t('New Region');
    }
}
```

Then use [block_get_blocks_by_region](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_get_blocks_by_region/7) in your template preprocess function to store the region blocks in a variable in order to be able to print them in your `.tpl` files.